# Stop / Pause swift app for period of time

Tags: cocoa, swift, nstimer

My app uses multiple threads of `NSTimer` Object.

Within the one function (called randomly at random times, not a fixed delay) I want it to pause the whole app, pause the threads for `1 second` only. I have the following code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(subscribe) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0 ];
```

Which is objective C, and I tried translating it into Swift like this:

```
self.performSelector(Selector:changeColourOfPage(), withObject: self, afterDelay: 1.0)
```

But I am getting the error `Missing argument for parameter 'waitUntilDone' in call` and when I put that in, it says it wants the argument `modes` but when I put that in it says `Extra argument modes`.

I cannot figure out how to pause the app and all it's threads for a couple of seconds, and then carry on like normal?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

The performSelector methods aren't available in Swift. You can get the delay functionality by using dispatch_after.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC * 1))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    changeColourOfPage() 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way in Swift 3.1

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
    changeColourOfPage()
}
```

You can substitute other units like `.milliseconds(1000)` or `.microseconds(1_000_000)` or `.nanoseconds(1_000_000_000)` for the time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer an old question, but just came along a better way to do this -

```
import Darwin //Put this line at the beginning of your file
func pauseForAMoment() {

        sleep(1)
        changeColorOfPage()

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a _better_ way to do this because it hangs the entire program when you call sleep(), but for this particular usage it works.